# Why do universal selectors not reset the user agent stylesheet

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<form action="/login">
  ...
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="pw">
  <br>
  <button>Log in</button>
</form>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font: 12px/20px Arial;
}
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

What made me feel puzzled is the `input`'s padding. Because I wrote these rules above

```
/* 
  to reset margins and paddings in the user agent stylesheet, which is expensive, but I did it just for testing.
*/ 
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*
  In my opinion, the following rules will result in a 198*18 content box with a 1px border surrounding it.
  While it didn't.
*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
```

The result is the `input` has 1px paddings, top and bottom. The snapshots is at the footer of the question. The universal selector didn't reset the padding for `input` elements.
What's the reason? Looking forward to the reply.

Snapshots: [removed]

**Hello, everyone. Sorry for the inconvenience. I finally found what's wrong with it. It has nothing to do with the code piece I cut off. Here is the pivotal snapshot. So what the hell is `\u200b`?**
[\u200b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHOMs.png)

To be honest, I should found the mistake earlier, because the universal selector rule didn't appear on the right panel. It's my fault.

Comment: Specificity. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @ksav — No. Specificity testing is step 3 of [the cascading order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order) but user agent vs author declarations are step 2.

Comment: I created a [test case](http://jsbin.com/jasuha/1/edit?html,css,output) and tried your code in Firefox and Chrome. The padding was successfully removed from the input in both browsers. I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I tried the same as @Quentin right now (https://jsfiddle.net/a51fy6jc/) and it is also overwritten right.

Comment: Yes, it's probably right time to ask, in what browser did you experience this problem?

Comment: It seems strange. I cut off some codes in order to make it more clear for you, which may resulting in not reproducing the problem. I will post details later. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Quentin Question updated and solved. It's my fault. Thank you for the reply. Sorry again.

Comment: @Sergej Updated and solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a [zero width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) character in your selector.

This renders the selector invalid, so it doesn't match anything, but is really hard to see in an editor.